# How to disable skype chat syncing?

Tags: skype

So Skype will let you (in the preferences) disable your chat history. If the other user also does the same, no chat history is saved, anywhere. However, it's a little impossible to ask every one of my Skype contacts to disable their chat history ;)

In any case, Skype has this pretty cool feature where if your log into skype from a location with no chat history, and you're chatting with somebody, Skype will automatically sync chat histories, so you can catch up, even if the other person kept talking after you left.

While this works great on desktops, it is absolutely disastrous on mobiles with ARM processors, simply because the processor isn't fast enough to handle the torrent of data that floods through.

There are reports of this happenning to iPhone users, and it absolutely cripples my N900 for several minutes while it's busy syncing up chats.

**tl;dr** Is there any way to disable chat syncing on my mobile device? I tried editing config.xml, but there doesn't seem to be an option to disable it...

```
<CentralStorage>
      <LastBackoff>0</LastBackoff>
      <LastFailure>0</LastFailure>
      <LastSync>1304514977</LastSync>
      <NeedSync>0</NeedSync>
      <SyncSet>
        <p>
          <avatar>40fabe76:2</avatar>
          <email>cdcf94a0:2</email>
          <profile>3aa645:2</profile>
        </p>

    etc ...
```